# C# Compare the Key Pressed on the Keyboard

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown, buttonclick, keyeventargs

I have a textbox and a button.I'm saving the value(keyboard key) entered in the TextBox.I need to give a message when I press  the right keyboard key.

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.text1 = text1.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == text1.Text) //--------->> error
    {
        MessageBox.Show("success");
    }
}
```

how can I provide this condition?

Comment: There are several practical problems with this code.  The distinction between the virtual key provided by KeyDown and the character provided by KeyPress is one.  But most severely, how would you ever type any text inside the textbox if you also have the form objecting against it?  The true intention is too hard to divine from the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe easier it will be to use [KeysConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keysconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            KeysConverter convertor = new KeysConverter();
            string keyPressed = convertor.ConvertToString(e.KeyValue);
            if (keyPressed == text1.Text)
            {
                //do stuff
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But, did not detect number keys.

Comment: @H.Marcus it does, please make sure that `KeyPreview` in your form is set to `True`

Comment: Yes, I did it before.

Comment: @H.Marcus which keys exactly it does not detect?

Comment: 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-0

Comment: @H.Marcus have you put a breakpoint on the first line inside the KeyDown event and tried to press "1"?

Comment: I did not fully understand the question.

Comment: on the first line of Form1_KeyDown() put a breakpoint(where KeysConverter is declared) put a breakpoint, press one on your keyboard and check if the event fires

Comment: are working with WPF or WinForms?
also try to create a new project to check if the problem reproduce

Comment: I will try but that is enough for me.Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you compare with one char text. You can try this.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt.Text.Length == 1 && e.KeyValue == (int)txt.Text[0]) //--------->> error
            {
                MessageBox.Show("success");
            }
        }
```

Comment: KeyEventArgs has no key defined, maybe you meant KeyCode?

Comment: @Başar Kaya Thank you for your answer.But, did not detect F keys and number keys.