# How to get keyboard key pressed c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to get the key pressed on the keyboard (not a specific), i watched somes "solutions" everywhere and i found nothing **working**. Conditions: Need anchoring a panel on the form.

- [C# Compare the Key Pressed on the Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49840440/c-sharp-compare-the-key-pressed-on-the-keyboard)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/input-keyboard/how-to-handle-forms?view=netdesktop-6.0
- This worked on a Console, i want the same without cancelling it! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Console.CancelKeyPress?view=net-6.0

  ```
    private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        KeysConverter convertor = new KeysConverter();
        string keyPressed = convertor.ConvertToString(e.KeyChar);
        if (keyPressed == "t")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("THIS IS T");
        }
    }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your Form1.cs

```cs
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.T)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("THIS IS T");
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, you put the focus on a button B and defined that if the A key is pressed, the code related to the A button will be executed.

Use code:

```cs
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message message, Keys KeyData)
{
    switch (KeyData)
    {
        case Keys. A:
            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```